# How can I compute the common points when spheres intersect?

Tags: intersection

When two spheres intersect they should share one or two points. I want to know how to compute those points?

I was thinking of something like this:

- -check if the spheres intersect
- -calculate `radius_1` distance from `center_1` in the direction of `center_2`
- -calculate `radius_2` distance from `center_2` in the direction of `center_1`
- -substract the smaller to the larger and have that one as "collision" point

This sounds to me a little too tricky, I wanted to know if there is a simplier way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this 2D or 3D? In 3D, the intersection of two spheres is a circle.

Comment: right! it is in 3d. np, the intersection circle could be approximated to its center

Comment: Here is a similar question with answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048701/finding-points-of-intersection-when-two-spheres-intersect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let `C₁` and `C₂` be the sphere centres, and `R₁` and `R₂` their radiuses. We pick a point `A` on the intersection circle and we want to find `B`, the centre of the [intersection circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere#Sphere-sphere_intersection):

[image: drawing]

Pythagoras gives us the following two equalities:

```
AB² = AC₁² - BC₁²
AB² = AC₂² - BC₂²
```

Combining the two and replacing AC₁ with R₁ and AC₂ with R₂:

```
BC₁² - BC₂² = R₁² - R₂²
```

We know that `C₁B + BC₂ = C₁C₂`:

```
                BC₁² - (C₁C₂ - BC₁)² = R₁² - R₂²
BC₁² - C₁C₂² - BC₁² + 2 * C₁C₂ * BC₁ = R₁² - R₂²
                      2 * C₁C₂ * BC₁ = R₁² - R₂² + C₁C₂²
                                 BC₁ = (R₁² - R₂² + C₁C₂²) / (2 * C₁C₂)
```

Giving us the final formula for the C₁B **vector**:

```
C₁B = (R₁² - R₂² + C₁C₂²) / (2 * C₁C₂²) * C₁C₂
```

Using pseudocode:

```
float P = dot(center_2 - center_1, center_2 - center_1);
float Q = (radius_1 * radius_1 - radius_2 * radius_2 + P) / (2.0f * P);
Point B = center_1 + Q * (center_2 - center_1);
```

Comment: @Hocevar maybe I am a bit slow but I don't think that we know BC2.. just because we don't exactly  know even where is B. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Leggy7 You can just calculate it. Since you know **R1** and **R2** you can calculate how far both circles overlap (second code snippet). **B** will always be in the middle of the overlapping area.

Comment: @Leggy7 the last line tells you where is B because it tells you what vector C1B is. If only we could use LaTeX formatting on this site, it would look a lot better.

Comment: @Leggy7 I added pseudocode using your variable names, hoping it's clearer now.

Comment: Excuseme sir, this is my first approach to this topic, so I'll need some explaination. what does the dot product of a vector with itself represent? geometrically, I mean

Comment: It is the square of its length. For a geometrical definition, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Your answer is accepted, thank you very much! I have one last question if you are so kind to help me. Since we are talking of Vector3, in c# XNA, it will be no enought to have the radius magnitude. I need to know even the intersection point with the other circle. Can I have that vector anyhow?

Comment: The variable `B` is already a `Point`. It is the centre of the intersection circle.

Comment: @samhocevar Could you please tell what are P and Q in the pseudocode ?

Comment: @wrangler they are just temporary variable names, to make the whole thing slightly more readable. They do not mean anything in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple method to compute the center of the intersection circle between two (hyper)spheres that works for every dimension (but 0D) using some vector notation.

Let **C1** and **C2** be the center of your (hyper)spheres, r1 and r2 the radii.

**D** := **C2** - **C1** is the vector that moves **C1** to **C2**; the leght of **D** (|**D**|) is the distance between centers.

Now d := |**D**| -(r1+r2) is the distance between the (hyper)spheres: positive menans no intersection, 0 menans point intersection, negative means intersection.

In the latter case, -d is an usefull measure of how much the spheres compenetrate.

Now the distance between **C1** and the center(**C**) we are looking for, is r1 - (-d)/2; being -d/2 the half distance and being substracted from r1 because r1 is "responsible" for "half compenetration".

Then  **C** = **D** /|**D**| * (r1+d/2)